# Overwrite PNG with 9 Patch and vice versa

Tags: android, image, resources, drawable, nine-patch

I have a library project with several app projects utilizing it.  Some of the app projects need PNG files for some of the drawables (i.e. background image) due to the fact that the image repeats (i.e. evenly spaced vertical bars) or would not look good if the edges stretch.  Other app projects have solid backgrounds that would be fine to have as 9 Patch images.

Sample Project Structure

Library
--res
----drawable-xxxx
------background.png
------some_image.9.png

OtherProject
--res
----drawable-xxxx
------background.9.png
------some_image.png

However, if I try to add the 9 Patch images to one of the projects, I get a compile time error that I have duplicate resources with the same name.  Is there an easy way to get around this without having to redefine the background file in each product (which would not be very maintainable)?

Comment: Rename the image, and program it to pick which one to use (possibly through a function call by the app using the library).  You can't have 2 resources with the same filename or it has no idea which one to pick.

Comment: Keep in mind the base names of resource files (after the removal of their extensions) need to be unique. In the case of 9-patch files, the base name is what's left after the ".9.png" is removed.

Comment: Looks like I was not wrong in thinking that it was not possible... I was merely looking for a more maintainable way to change the resource without having to add code for every project.  It seems to me that the compiler could have been written to look for resource files with the same base name, rather than file name to overwrite with the main project's resource.  Gabe, if you post your comment as an answer it will be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gabe Sechan and scottt pointed out in comments to the question, the name of the files has to be unique to identify them.